# How to get the step counter data immediately, without the person needing to walk for the data to be read?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am doing a pedometer app, and I am struggling with the pedometer.

I am using this API:
[Step counter](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion#sensors-motion-stepcounter)

I am currently overriding the onSensorChanged method, but this causes that the steps are only read when the user is walking.

How can I just read the most recent event from the sensor? I need this data when the app is started up to see how many steps they gained while the app was closed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the example code it says this:

> // If the max delay is 0, events will be delivered in continuous mode without batching.

https://github.com/android/sensors-samples/blob/main/BatchStepSensor/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/batchstepsensor/BatchStepSensorFragment.java

Have you tried that?

```
sensorManager.registerListener(listener, sensor, SensorManager. SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST, 0)
```